# Rails Todo List app > Tasks printing with all table records at the end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on simple Todo List app which I want to print this output (all todo_task table records -> [] brackets after "pranie" task):

```
Title: a

Description: b

hey

albo

pranie
[#<TodoTask id: 1, todo_list_id: 1, content: "hey", created_at: "2015-09-09 12:46:11", updated_at: "2015-09-09 12:46:11">, #<TodoTask id: 2, todo_list_id: 1, content: "albo", created_at: "2015-09-09 12:48:42", updated_at: "2015-09-09 12:48:42">, #<TodoTask id: 3, todo_list_id: 1, content: "pranie", created_at: "2015-09-09 12:57:15", updated_at: "2015-09-09 12:57:15">]
```

Other files content:
app/controllers/todo_tasks_controller.rb :

```
class TodoTasksController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_todo_list
  before_action :set_todo_task, except: [:create, :index]

  def create
    @todo_task = @todo_list.todo_tasks.create(todo_task_params)
    redirect_to @todo_list
  end

  def destroy
    @todo_task.destroy
    redirect_to @todo_list
  end

  def index
  end

  private

  def set_todo_list
    @todo_list = TodoList.find(params[:todo_list_id])
  end

  def set_todo_task
    @todo_task = @todo_list.todo_tasks.find(params[:id])
  end

  def todo_task_params
    params.require(:todo_task).permit(:content)
  end
end
```

app/views/todo_lists/index.html.erb :

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @todo_list.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= @todo_list.description %>
</p>

<%= @todo_list.todo_tasks.each do |task| %>
    <p><%= task.content %></p>
<% end %>

<%= render 'todo_tasks/form' %>
```

app/views/todo_lists/_form.html.erb :

```
<%= form_for([@todo_list, @todo_list.todo_tasks.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.text_field :content, placeholder: 'New Todo' %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
<%= @todo_list.todo_tasks.each do |task| %>
    <p><%= task.content %></p>
<% end %>
```

to

```
<% @todo_list.todo_tasks.each do |task| %>
    <p><%= task.content %></p>
<% end %>
```

Notice the change `<%=` to `<%`.

`<% %>` - Executes the statement/expression.

`<%= %>` - Prints the output.

Comment: Simple as that! Thanks :) I guess these are just a blind newbie problems.

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: @SheinAlexey Look carefully.

Comment: '<%=' tells ERB what follows is an expression unlike '<%'

Comment: Almost broke my eyes, but finally noticed (and proposed a change to save other people's eyes )